# Power Bi Measure with non aggregated String

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to let a Measure show multiple String values, which are not aggregated using `CONCATENATEX(), FIRSTNONBLANK()` etc.?

My Data looks like this:

| id | MaterialNumber |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 3 |
| c | 2 |
| c | 3 |

Goal I want to achieve in Power BI:

1. Slicing to id = a
2. displaying Materialnumbers of id = a
3. choose a materialnumber, e.g. Materialnumber = 1
4. Displaying all id's in a matrix where Materialnumber = 1, in this case a & b. The rest of the visuals should stay filtered.

I failed to write a measure for step 4).
This one has the right functionality, but I want to display separate Strings (to copy them out of the matrix):

```
Selected Associated Ids = 

CALCULATE(
  CONCATENATEX(
   Data
   ,Data[id]
   ,UNICHAR(10)
  )
  ,FILTER(
    all(Data)
    ,Data[MaterialNumber] = SELECTEDVALUE(Report[MaterialNumber])
  )
)
```

I also tried this, which failed due to the well known Error:

> A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

A lot of people solve this by using FIRSTNONBLANK() which does not fit my case, because i want to have all results, not only the first one. In this case, a & b.:

```
LOOKUPVALUE(
  Report[PATH_ID]
  ,Report[MATNR]
  ,SELECTEDVALUE(Report[MATNR])
)
```

Using Power BI Desktop Cloud 2.86.902.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate table to act as a slicer on `id` and `MaterialNumber`.

A calculated table like:

```
Slicer = SUMMARIZE ( Data, Data[id], Data[MaterialNumber] )
```

Then you can filter your matrix visual with a measure in the filter pane, i.e., [ShowId] = 1.

```
ShowId =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Slicer[MaterialNumber] )
        IN CALCULATETABLE (
            VALUES ( Data[MaterialNumber] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( Data, Data[id] )
        ),
    1
)
```